# jquery function on ajax loaded content

Tags: jquery, ajax

How do I select objects and apply functions to them if they are loaded in with Ajax?

This code works, but I would like this code to run without the click event. So it runs automatically.

```
$(document).on("click",".button",function(e){

    var imgcount = $('.slider img').length;
    var slidesize = 100 / imgcount
    var innersize = 100 * imgcount

    $('.slider img').wrap('<div class="slide" />');
    $('.slide').wrapAll('<div class="inner" />');
    $('.inner').wrapAll('<div class="overflow" />');
    $('.slide').css('width', slidesize + '%');
    $('.inner').css('width', innersize + '%');

    });
```

This is how I load in my content

```
$('.work-item-hover').click(function(){

    var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content-post > *';
    $('#content-post').slideUp('normal',loadContent);
    $('#load').remove();
    $('.content-post-wrap').append('<span id="load">LOADING...</span>');
    $('#load').fadeIn('normal');
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-5);
    function loadContent() {
        $('#content-post').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
    }
    function showNewContent() {
        $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
    $('#content-post').slideDown('slow',hideLoader());
});
```

Comment: I do not see where ajax comes into play here, please elaborate. Else `$(document).ready(...)` might be your simplest solution.

Comment: All of these elements (slider img, slide, inner) they are all loading in with ajax.

Comment: Maybe instead of onclick register this function with (or execute it from) the success method of your ajax call?

Comment: I updated the post with the load in call to show you where I'm loading in the content.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more how I would register it with the success? I'm new to jQuery. Trying to learn :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case the `showNewContent()` is your success method. You could insert your code there (or wrap it in a another named function for convenience).

```
function showNewContent() {       

    var imgcount = $('.slider img').length;
    var slidesize = 100 / imgcount
    var innersize = 100 * imgcount

    $('.slider img').wrap('<div class="slide" />');
    $('.slide').wrapAll('<div class="inner" />');
    $('.inner').wrapAll('<div class="overflow" />');
    $('.slide').css('width', slidesize + '%');
    $('.inner').css('width', innersize + '%');

    $('#content-post').slideDown('slow',hideLoader());
}
```

Note that I removed the call to `.ajaxComplete()` as it is imho redundant since `showNewContent()` is registered to `.load()` as the `complete handler` here `.load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())` (and only for this single request). With your original call you register for all ajax requests.

[sandboxed test](http://jsfiddle.net/U7KDX/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Trigger the **click event explicitly**

```
    $('.slide').css('width', slidesize + '%');
    $('.inner').css('width', innersize + '%');
}).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(document).ready(function(){});` - other than that, make sure your call `$('element').click();` in your success function of any AJAX request.